# Protractor :e2e : Allure report : Issue with allure.createStep

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor, allure

I am using allure report and facing  a issue with allure.createStep. When the report is generated then the attachment is not getting added to the first step '**Click on Add Button**' infact it is getting added to the next step '**Candidate Add Button**'
Here screenshot 1 shifted to next step and same happened for screenshot 2 :

[image]

Below is the code I am using :->

```
     async function attachScreenshot(filename: string) {
          browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment(filename, function () {
              return Buffer.from(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
          })
        }
    
    
        fit('Create Candidate', async () => {
            await browser.refresh();
    // First Step
             await allure.createStep("Click on Add Button ", async () => {
            await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(SpadesPageObj.add), 20000, 'Add Button');
            await SpadesPageObj.add.click();
             await attachScreenshot('1');
            })();
            
    // Second Step
    
    await allure.createStep("Candidate Add Button", async () => {
              await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(SpadesPageObj.candidate), 20000, 'Add Candidate Button');
              await SpadesPageObj.candidate.click();
              await attachScreenshot('2');
            })();
            // await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(SpadesPageObj.candidate), 20000, 'Add Candidate Button');
            // await SpadesPageObj.candidate.click();
            // await allure.createAttachment('Candidate Add Button ', new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
            //});
//Third step
            await allure.createStep("Resume upload", async () => {
              var path = require('path');
              var remote = require('../../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
              browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
              var fileToUpload = './resume.docx';
              var absolutePath = path.resolve(process.cwd() + fileToUpload);
              await element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
              await attachScreenshot('3');
        })();
          })
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because I have not used await in the attachScreenshot function.

```
async function attachScreenshot(filename: string) {
     await browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
        allure.createAttachment(filename, function () {
          return Buffer.from(png, 'base64')
        }, 'image/png')();
      })
    }
```

Thank you very much :)